# Joining multiple models to create activity feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm having difficulty getting a scope to work in a Rails app with a pg database. In the show page for groups_controller.rb, I'm trying to display two different types of data ordered by created_at. The first is users who joined the group and second, users who have confirmed attendance for any of the events for the group, and the results could be mixed together like this

```
user joined group  (7 minutes ago)
user confirmed attendance (10 minutes ago)
user joined group (15 minutes ago)
```

The models are as following

Group.rb

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :users, through: :memberships

has_many :events
```

User.rb

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :groups, through: :memberships

has_many :confirmations
has_many :events, through: :confirmations
```

Event.rb

```
 has_many :confirmations
 has_many :users, through: :confirmations
```

In the show action of the groups_controller.rb, I created a recent_activities action like this, passing Time.now with the intention of using it to  get all the results for the last 24 hours

```
def show
@recent = Group.recent_activities(Time.now)

end
```

However, when it came to writing the method in group.rb, I ran into problems. For example, using this format

```
where( memberships: {created_at: ''}
```

I didn't know how to calculate within the last 24 hours, or within the last 7 days. I'm sure there's other problems with how I'm trying to do this. Any tips? I've only written a few of these types of queries in my life so they've coming out all mishapen

```
Group.rb

 scope :recent_activities, lambda {|time|
    joins(:user, :membership, :confirmation, :event).
    where( memberships: {created_at: ''},
           confirmations: {created_at: '' })

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
scope :recent_activities, lambda{ |time|
  joins({:memberships => :users}, {:events => :confirmations}).
  where('CAST(memberships.created_at as DATE) > :yesterday 
         AND CAST(confirmations.created_at as DATE) > :yesterday', 
         yesterday: Date.today - 1.days)

}
```

(You could add the following relation in your Group model:)

```
has_many :events
has_many :confirmations, :through => :events
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. Can you write out the whole method? Is it important for your solution to note that there is no association between confirmation and group. `Group has_many :events,  events has_many :confirmations` or does that not matter?

Comment: I just uploaded my answer. This is a very complex query to achieve, with complex relations! @Leahcim

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer just to show that you can use [ago](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-ago), [since](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-since) methods.

So you could do something like this for "since the last 24 hours" of the `time` parameter.

```
scope :recent_activities, lambda {|time|
  joins(:user, :membership, :confirmation, :event).
  where("memberships.created_at >= :twenty_four_hours_ago and confirmations.created_at >= :twenty_four_hours_ago", twenty_four_hours_ago: 24.hours.ago(time))
}
```

Comment: I got this error: `Association named 'confirmation' was not found on Group; perhaps you misspelled it?`No direct relation between groups and confirmations. Is there a way to modify your answer to account for that? Thanks

Comment: @Leahcim, It appears that you already found the solution.  As MrYoshiji has pointed, you needed to define that `has_many :confirmations, through: :events`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to create a feed activity, take a look at [this](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) gem, it may help you.
You can see this [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity) too